# sum of uniform and binomial distributions

Tags: probability-theory, summation, random-variables

Random variable ξ has a uniform distribution on [0, 1], and η is its independent binomial random variable Bin(n, p). Find the density of the random
variable ξ + η.

My steps so far:

1. η is a discrete random variable, ξ is absolutely continuous random variable

let's do the following: $$F_{\xi + \eta}(t) = P(\xi + \eta \leq t) = P(\bigsqcup\limits_{k=0}^{n}(\eta = k \cap \xi \leq t - k)) = \sum_{k =0}^{n}P((\eta = k) \cap(\xi\leq t-k)) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}P(\eta = k)P(\xi \leq t- k) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}(t-k)$$

P.S. where did (t - k) come from? $$\int_{0}^{t-k}\frac{1}{1 - 0}dt = t - k$$

so after this I'm stuck and can't come up with something how to get final formula, please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]
Hint: if $\xi + \eta = X$, then the integer part of $X$ is $\lfloor X \rfloor = \eta$ and the fractional part is $\{X \} = \xi$. For any real number $y$,
$X \le y$ if either $\eta < \lfloor y \rfloor$, or $\eta = \lfloor y \rfloor$ and $\xi \le \{y\}$.

So the CDF is

$$ F_X(y) = \sum_{0 \le k < \lfloor y\rfloor} {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} + {n \choose {\lfloor y \rfloor}} p^{\lfloor y \rfloor} (1-p)^{n - \lfloor y \rfloor} \{ y \} $$
and the derivative of this is the PDF
$$ f_X(y) = {n \choose {\lfloor y \rfloor}} p^{\lfloor y \rfloor} (1-p)^{n - \lfloor y \rfloor}$$

Comment: maybe you meant that integer part of X is η? η got Binomial distribution, so it can be only integer positive number. ?

Comment: actually it seems like this way is not better than mine. I have similar problem as in my first approach because it is not clear how to transform the sum into final formula. if you could help me out how to find the sum I'd be really grateful, because I've been trying to come up with it for a long time already

Comment: Yes, I had $\xi$ and $\eta$ reversed.  Fixed it now

Comment: The sum depends only on the integer part $\lfloor y \rfloor$, so its derivative (when the fractional part is nonzero) is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that when you write
$$\Pr[\xi + \eta \le t] = \Pr\left[\bigcup_{k=0}^\color{red}{n} \,(\eta = k) \cap (\xi \le t-k)\right],$$
you must remember that whenever $k > t$, the event $\xi \le t-k$ has probability $0$, and you did not take this into account.  The second issue is that when $t - k > 1$, then $\Pr[\xi \le t-k] = 1$, and you also did not account for this when you wrote $\Pr[\xi \le t-k] = t-k$.  So your next steps should read
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[\xi + \eta \le t]
&= \Pr\left[\bigcup_{k=0}^n \,(\eta = k) \cap (\xi \le t-k)\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \Pr[\xi \le t-k] \\
&= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor t \rfloor - 1} \binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \right) + \binom{n}{\lfloor t \rfloor} p^{\lfloor t \rfloor} (1-p)^{n - \lfloor t \rfloor} (t-\lfloor t \rfloor). \\
\end{align}$$
This is because when $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, \lfloor t \rfloor - 1\}$, then $t - k > 1$, hence $\Pr[\xi \le t-k] = 1$.  For these values of $k$, the contribution to the CDF consists of the entire probability masses from the binomial distribution.  Then when $k = \lfloor t \rfloor$, there is a fractional contribution to the CDF, where the fraction is $t - \lfloor t \rfloor$ because this is the part of $t$ that the continuous uniform variable on $[0,1]$ is giving.

Then, the density is the derivative with respect to $t$.  The first term gives a derivative of $0$ because although the upper index of summation depends on $t$, it is a stepwise constant function; i.e., $\frac{d}{dt}[\lfloor t\rfloor] = 0$ whenever $t$ is not an integer.  For the same reason, the only factor in the second term that continuously varies as a function of $t$ is $t - \lfloor t \rfloor$, so
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[\binom{n}{\lfloor t \rfloor} p^{\lfloor t \rfloor} (1-p)^{n - \lfloor t \rfloor} (t-\lfloor t \rfloor)\rfloor \right] = \binom{n}{\lfloor t \rfloor} p^{\lfloor t \rfloor} (1-p)^{n - \lfloor t \rfloor} \frac{d}{dt}[t - \lfloor t \rfloor]$$
and again, since $\lfloor t \rfloor$ is a stepwise constant function of $t$,
$$\frac{d}{dt}[t - \lfloor t \rfloor] = \frac{d}{dt}[t] - \frac{d}{dt}[\lfloor t \rfloor] = 1 - 0 = 1.$$  Therefore, the density is
$$f_{\xi + \eta}(t) = \binom{n}{\lfloor t \rfloor} p^{\lfloor t \rfloor} (1-p)^{n - \lfloor t \rfloor}, \quad 0 \le t \le n+1.$$
(Note that if $t = n+1$, $\binom{n}{\lfloor t \rfloor} = 0$ so there is no issue with the factor $(1-p)^{n-\lfloor t\rfloor}$ having a negative exponent.)